# Detect Line with OpenCV from camera input

Tags: opencv, image-processing, serial-port

Right now I am working on a project that requires me to detect when a perforated line is in the middle of the video image and then output a serial command to control a cutter arm. I am new to OpenCV and not exactly sure how to do it.

Comment: What have you read? What have you tried? Start by reading up on hough transforms and basic image processing.

Comment: @dr.mo I have looked at basic hough transforms and looked at links like the following [link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html) One of the biggest things that I have yet to figure out is how to send a command once the perforation is detected in the center of the screen.

Comment: Ok, so you can detect the line but can't send a command when you've detected it? Where does this command have to be sent to?

Comment: @dr.mo I am unsure how to call a program when just one line is in the center of the video image. For example if i wanted to call a python program to send a serial command.

Comment: I think that is really a separate question

Comment: @dr.mo is there anything that you could direct me towards???

Comment: you can use python from c++ via a library. please do some searching on google yourself and try things out. come back if you have a specific question

Comment: @dr.mo I have done some more research and I started a new thread that was more specific in what I was looking for... [New Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993846/detect-line-in-center-of-video-opencv)