# Detect Line in center of video OpenCV

Tags: python, linux, opencv, line

Right now I am working on a project that requires me to detect when a perforated line is in the middle of the video image and then output a serial command to control a cutter arm. Right now I can detect lines that are vertical (which is what I want), However I can not detect just when they are in the center of the screen. Also I imagine that using the output from the following line I could tell that there are lines being detected?:

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, math.pi/1, 1, None, 23, 1)
```

My main question is as follows using OpenCV/python how do I detect vertical lines that are just in the center of the video output in order to count how many perforated sets have passed the camera and on X stop and cut when lined up?????

Picture of what I would like to possibly see
https://www.dropbox.com/s/13v9g92uw40riiq/good.png

Full Working code bellow:

```
import cv2
import os
import math
import numpy
import scipy

vc =cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if vc.isOpened():
rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
rval = False

while rval:
rval, frame = vc.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 80, 120, apertureSize=3)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, math.pi/1, 1, None, 23, 1)    #20-25 works well 

if lines != None:       
    for line in lines[0]:
        pt1 = (line[0],line[1])
        pt2 = (line[2],line[3])
        cv2.line(frame, pt1, pt2, (0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imshow("edge", frame)
ch = cv2.waitKey(50)

if ch != -1:
    print "keypressed"
    print ch
    break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Why don't you simply check the coordinates of the line?

Comment: @guneykayim I am trying to figure out how to do that but if I had to take a guess the top left of the frame would be coordinate (0,0).

I would imagine that adding a condition statement in the for loop could set a range of values to look for and pass if they fall in the desired range?

Also when the object is moving it has a hard time lining up the lines and tracking them even at slow speeds. Any ideas on that???

Comment: yes, define a rectangle in the middle of the image and then check the coordinates of the lines (i.e. start and end points) to see if they are inside the box or not.

Comment: the issue you are seeing with movements is most likely due to motion blur. this reduces high frequencies and hence the edges. have a look at your edge image during motion. do the edges still show? if not then a solution would be to use a higher shutter speed on your video camera which probably means you need more light.

Comment: Well, you don't need coordinate of the frame. You need width (cols) and height (rows) of the frame, which you can get directly from your frame. Then you just need to find the center of the line. If it is defined as two points (x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2 is your line center. Then check if this line center is around width/2, height/2.

Comment: And for the second problem as @dr.mo said, you need a better imaging system.

Comment: I will try the above when I get back to the office tomorrow, and there will be more light and a higher resolution sensor used in the final product (it is currently being shipped to us). I will post what I have towards the end of the day. Thank you all who have helped clear up a couple of things for me.

Comment: Checking to make sure that the lines are within the boundaries makes it work quite well and I can check different zones to increase or decrease the speed at which the product moves to line up. Thank you all for the help.